# How do I determine which phone line goes where, without any special tools?

Tags: phone-wiring

I have six (6) phone lines running from my rooms into the basement. They are not terminated as this is a new build. I need to determine which line corresponds to which room.

Is there a way to do this without purchasing a line tester?

Comment: I've never tried it but a 9 volt battery and a voltage detector.  Maybe there will be enough juice to make it thru with the voltage drop.

Comment: They're still putting phone lines in houses? :)

Comment: @DA01 not really, but I requested them (at no extra cost). I have some DIY automation stuff I expect to keep me busy for the next few years.

Comment: @lqlarry -  Thanks, the 9V battery really did the trick. It's amazing how simple old-fashioned solutions can save the day. You should've made yours an answer.

Comment: Didn't know if it would do it so I didn't put it as an answer.  I'm glad it worked and I hope I remember that the next time I'm stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest route would be to use a circuit tester on the various lines in your basement, and have a friend temporarily short the lines in each of the rooms.

An audible circuit tester makes this very easy. It can be a standalone circuit checker, or as part of a multimeter's functionality. It raises a voltage across a circuit, and if that circuit is complete current flows, sounding a buzzer.

If you have a multimeter, look for a speaker icon to see if yours can do this.

As @lqlarry said, you could do this with a 9V battery but that shouldn't be needed - the voltage drop should be negligible.

Comment: This answer could be a bit better if you explain a bit more, and instead of saying "circuit tester", explain how you're using a multimeter to check resistance.

Comment: updated @gregmac. Betterer?

Comment: I took @lqlarry's idea and bought a 9V battery and a voltage tester. Total cost approximately $14.

Answer (score 1):

Well I think you know already that the typical way to find these is with a tone generator kit (line tester), however, the simpliest way is to simply plug a phone in to the end of the drop, and then connect the drops to the feed (patch panel/NID/etc) one by one until you hear a dial tone on the phone. When you hear the dial tone, you know what line you've connected.  The step by step process works like this:

1. Terminate the end where you will plug a phone in (install a jack).
2. Plug a phone into the jack you just installed; verify there is no dial tone
3. Head downstairs (or where ever all your wires are located).  Pick any cable and connect the red/green pair to the live service (probably the red/green pair too)
4. Go back to the phone - check for dial tone.  If you have a dial tone, you know what cable it is.  Now repeat for other phones.
5. If you didn't hear a dial tone,  disconnect the cable and try another, and repeat the process until you find which one it is.

Comment: Sorry, but you used a few big words there. If I plug a phone on one end, does the phone generate enough juice to test with a circuit tester?

Comment: No, the idea is that you have a phone plugged into a dead line - no dial tone. Now hookup the wires one by one until you get a dialtone - now you know what wire it is. Will require lots of running around in the house, however

Comment: I've added more details to the post to hopefuly help!

Comment: Got it. However, I am not connecting the lines to the PSTN. I just need to connect two (2) of the six (6) lines to an ATA adapter. Didn't want to spent all that much to get all the lines terminated.

Answer (score 1):

I used a 9 volt battery and a multi-meter tester.  Fist, I Hooked the solid blue wire to the positive post on the battery and then I attached the whitestripe/ blue wire to the negative post.  Then I went down the basement where all the wires go into the phone box ( I had 10 wires hanging down there and none of them had been hooked up).  I started testing the solid blue wire and  whitestripe/ blue wires from each of the cat5 wires hanging down there in the basement with a multi tester.  Suddenly the meter pegged and when it did this I knew that I had the wire that was attached to the 9 volt battery up stairs.  This could be done alone as long as you can figure out how to attach the small little wires to the top of the 9 volt bettery.  I was lucky to have a snap on plastic protector from one of my 9 volt batteries  handy and used this to snap those little wires to the top of the battery.  Not sure what the correct setting on the multi-meter tester was.  Just google this part. When I googled it I someone said to  to set the multi-meter to the DC setting and moving the selector to at least the 40 volt range.  This seemed to work well for me.   Good luck